# Web Form Security

Tags: php, security, forms, cookies, header

I set a cookie in the headers with an md5 hashed keyword. Then in my code, it checks for the exact matching cookie before displaying a form. Is this pretty much pointless? The form submits to an external site, so I am trying to secure the form without using captcha..

Comment: It's like putting a lock on the door and giving everyone a key.

Comment: Cookie wouldn't be sent to the external site

Comment: damn it, figures.. ok what if I process the form with captcha on my own server and then send the results to the other site? Not sure how to do that exactly, but that should atleast work i think?

Comment: the goal is to have a form on my site that people can fill out with lyrics, but then I need the information to be sent to a different site. The other site accepts information like this: "?artist=Eminem&title=Not Afraid&album=Recovery&lyrics=".. So hte form I have is set to GET and can send the form information to that site, but I don't want people spamming the external site through mine..

Comment: A cookie will be sent to the remote site,  so long as that remote site has set a cookie on that browser.   Further more i am not exactly sure what you are trying to defened against, perhaps CSRF?  is this request really useful to an attacker or is it just BS like a search request?

Comment: yea, I just don't want jackasses spamming the other site with ads, etc.. So captcha or some kind of thing that confirms they are human is all I need.. But all the information I read was about web forms being submitted to own server..

Comment: Django uses honeypot fields, i.e., extra fields in the form, that are hidden with CSS and thus reveal (probably) a bot, if they are filled out. Although this is no guarantee to catch all bots, it's a simple and lightweight method to start with.

Comment: @brandon14_99  well a spammer isn't going to use a web browser,  so you have to use a Captcha to stop the bots.

Comment: @The Rook thanks for the info, I am aware captcha is my best bet, but I was first looking for alternate methods like @Boldewyn mentioned. I think I will try that first.

Comment: @brandon14_99 That is  security though obscurity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  Thats not going to stop someone from writing a bot to target your site.

Comment: hmm... good call. guess i will look for some kind of captcha system that can get validated through ajax and not require form submit, because the form, once submitted, will be sent to the external site..

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is only a problem if the request is valuable to the attacker.   For instance, if can an attacker can get a logged in administrator to change their password using CSRF,  then you have a **serious** problem.   No one cares about lyrics,  or search requests or page navigation.  No one will ever exploit that,  so it doesn't matter where the request comes from.

Comment: I won't say that. If someone can inject some Javascript on a lyrics page, that ranks acceptably high in Google, he can do pretty much harm with that. Cracking bank sites is not the only target for black hats.

Comment: @Boldewyn that is XSS not CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the cookie at the same time as you print the form it will always return true, unless they have cookies turned off.

What the cookie check is used for is cross site request forgery prevention. In other words, stop people from submitting forms from external sites :)

So what you have described there, doesn't do anything

Comment: -1 cookies cannot defended against CSRF.  The whole point of csrf is riding on the session and the cookie value will be included with the forged GET or POST query.

Comment: @the rook, sorry I didn't explain myself properly

When you do a CSRF check, you put a md5hash in a cookie and in a hidden field in the form and then check that they match.

You do the check when you process the post information.

Comment: I removed the -1 becuase that would stop it.  although md5 is a inefficient method of making a random number and it still comes down to what you are taking md5() of,  if its a value known to the attacker then it doesn't matter.  It would also be better to store the token in a session variable instead of a cookie.

Comment: using a session or a cookie, which you use doesn't matter. The reason for this is that the attacker in csrf isn't a person, it is a website. This website will be under a different domain so the browser will prevent the attacker from knowing the md5hash (which of course is generated on every load on the form), since a cookie will only be sent to the domain it originated from. ps. don't care much about the -1, just like discussing things :P